# HTML5 Audio generating wavefrom from .wav file

Tags: html5-audio, waveform, audiowaveform

How would I make this random SVG waveform generator, generate waveform from audio file;

```
` 
 https://codepen.io/andrewscofield/pen/oGyrEv  `
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.
https://codepen.io/Stepancic/pen/ExmZpZj?editors=0010

The main part here is

```
  var y1 = (config.line_height - filteredData[i] * config.line_height) / 2;
  var y2 = config.line_height - y1;
```

that gets drawn in the for loop.
The multiplier in `y1` is just here to make filteredData value "bigger".

Sample rate isn't dynamically generated so you can change the `const samples = 92;` value depending on your audio file length.

This code still has some work to be done, but I hope it helps.
BR